# Issue with "npm create vite@latest" for React: Unable to Initialize Project

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to create a new React project using the command `npm create vite@latest`. Despite following the documentation and ensuring that I have the latest version of Vite installed, the initialization process seems to be failing specifically for React projects.

```bash
[vite] Internal server error: The service is no longer running
  Plugin: vite:esbuild
  File: D:/Projects/Personal/Java Script/MERN/my-react-app/src/main.jsx
      at D:\Projects\Personal\Java Script\MERN\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:828:29
      at sendRequest (D:\Projects\Personal\Java Script\MERN\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:700:14)
      at start (D:\Projects\Personal\Java Script\MERN\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:826:9)
      at Object.transform2 [as transform] (D:\Projects\Personal\Java Script\MERN\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:891:5)  
      at D:\Projects\Personal\Java Script\MERN\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2231:77
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Object.transform (D:\Projects\Personal\Java Script\MERN\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2231:36)
      at transform (D:\Projects\Personal\Java Script\MERN\my-react-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2049:62)
      at transformWithEsbuild (file:///D:/Projects/Personal/Java%20Script/MERN/my-react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:14537:30)
      at TransformContext.transform (file:///D:/Projects/Personal/Java%20Script/MERN/my-react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:14612:38)
      at Object.transform (file:///D:/Projects/Personal/Java%20Script/MERN/my-react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:64060:62)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///D:/Projects/Personal/Java%20Script/MERN/my-react-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-V3BH7oO1.js:49741:29)
```

Command used:

```bash
npm create vite@latest my-react-app --template react
```

Installed versions:

- Node.js: v20.10.0
- npm: v10.2.3

Steps taken:

- Confirming the installation of the latest Vite version.
- Checking the compatibility of Node.js and npm versions.
- Trying different variations of the command.

I've already searched through relevant documentation and discussions but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: When i run with `npm run dev` it prompts `Internal server error: The service is no longer running`. Is there an issue with vite currently?

Comment: Have you tried with a different command tool?

Comment: Did you try `npm create vite@latest` and select `react` when it asks in the next step?

Comment: Yes and when i run it prompts an error

Comment: It seems that this error is generally linked to the behavior of the **antivirus** running on your operating system. **Try** disabling it **temporarily** and then run the command again. If this works, read your antivirus documentation to insert an exception.

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce your problem, but the command-line that you show is not correct. If you want a one-liner to create a vite typescript react app, you need to add two dashes between the name of the app and the --template argument, as in

```
npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react
```

For me, the command-line that you are using will prompt for TypeScript/JavaScript and choice of framework, and ignore the 'template' argument.